# Python variable name not defined in dict comprehension inside an enum class

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, namespaces, closures

I am using Python 2.7 and I am trying to define an enum class

```
from test_module import BannerType
class LoginBannerType:
    Login_Banner_Flag = 1 << 4
    VALUE_TO_NAME = dict(
        (k, v) for k, v in BannerType.VALUE_TO_NAME.items() if (k & Login_Banner_Flag))
```

Here `Login_Banner_Flag` refers to the class-level attribute I just defined but when I try import this enum class, I got this error:

```
(k, v) for k, v in BannerType.VALUE_TO_NAME.items() if (k & Login_Banner_Flag))
NameError: global name 'Login_Banner_Flag' is not defined
```

I tried to change that line to the following but it does not work either:

```
VALUE_TO_NAME = dict(
        (k, v) for k, v in BannerType.VALUE_TO_NAME.items() if (k & LoginBannerType.Login_Banner_Flag))
```

So it is a comprehension and I am supposed to get reference to outer variables right? What is wrong with my code and how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a generator, which has its own function scope. Moreover a class doesn't have a scope until it's definition is completely. Which means your generator simply *cannot* reference `Login_Banner_Flag`.

This is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/release/2.7.11/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding):

> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. If a local
>   variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the
>   definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks
>   contained within the defining one, unless a contained block introduces
>   a different binding for the name. **The scope of names defined in a
>   class block is limited to the class block; it does not extend to the
>   code blocks of methods – this includes comprehensions and generator
>   expressions since they are implemented using a function scope.** This
>   means that the following will fail:
>
> ```
> class A:
>     a = 42
>     b = list(a + i for i in range(10))
> ```
>
> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
>   enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is
>   called the block’s environment.

This is the same reason why the following fails:

```
class A:
    x = 1
    def a(self):
        print(x)   # you have to use A.x

A().a()   #error! x isn't defined
```

However in your case the problem is that you *cannot* even use `LoginBannerType.Login_Banner_Flag` because the class `LoginBannerType` doesn't exist until the end of the declaration and the generator requires that value before that point.

To solve this you can:

1. Populate that dictionary *after* the class is created:

   ```
   from test_module import BannerType
   class LoginBannerType:
       Login_Banner_Flag = 1 << 4
       VALUE_TO_NAME = {}

       # etc

   LoginBannerType.VALUE_TO_NAME = dict(... #use LoginBannerType.Login_Banner_Flag)
   ```
2. Use a decorator, which basically is like doing 1 but hiding it inside an `@initialize_class`
3. Use the default argument hack to get the value from the class scope:

   ```
   from test_module import BannerType
   class LoginBannerType:
       Login_Banner_Flag = 1 << 4
       def f(flag=Login_Banner_Flag):
           return dict((k, v) for k, v in BannerType.VALUE_TO_NAME.items() if (k & flag))
       VALUE_TO_NAME = f()
       del f
   ```

Comment: Note that in Python 2 a list comprehension will work fine(your docs link points to Python 3): `dict([...])` OP is using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Both `Login_Banner_Flag` and `VALUE_TO_NAME` are class variables not visible to each other.

Inline `Login_Banner_Flag`:

```
(k & (1 << 4))
```